# C# order list with dynamicaly set property

Tags: c#

I have list which item has many properties.

I can sort for example by "Name" property:

```
var newList = list.OrderBy(x=>x.Name).ToList();
```

I am searching for solution to select order property programaticaly, for example like:

```
var newList = list.OrderBy(x=>x["House"]).ToList(); // error
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Use the reflection. `x.GetType().GetProperty("House", BindingFlags.GetProperty || BindingFlags.Public).GetValue(x)`